# Fetch POST value in coldfusion from objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coldfusion, nsurlconnection

I am trying to post a string to a URL in iphone which will be retrieved by the server. The server side scripting is done in coldfusion. I am trying to fetch the data in coldfusion and pass on the value back to iphone. I am not familiar much with coldfusion and wanted some help in this. Below is the coding in iphone :

/** Iphone code **/

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abc.com/test.cfm"];


NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

/**Coldfusion code **/

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<cfoutput>#form.post#</cfoutput>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I doing it correctly ?

Comment: What do you see when you dump the FORM scope? `<cfdump var="#FORM#">`

Comment: Dump the raw request data `<cfdump var="#gethttpRequestData()#">` and the #URL# scope too for good measure. What do you see? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c11.html

Comment: Is your POST sending a *named variable*?

Comment: Hi Leigh: I have changed my code to Pritesh`s answer :NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"post=Hello%20World"]; and it works correct !!!!

Comment: Hi lefmoveson - Ah okay. So you just needed to name the variable. Glad it is working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to specify name of form variable in data. Try below for post variable. I haven't tested it should work.

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"post=Hello%20World"];
```

Comment: Hi Pritesh, Thank you for the reply. I am not sure also how should I check in coldfusion if the data has been fetched ? am I writing the code correctly ?

Comment: Normally you can debug it but for quick review create PDF document with dump of content.

Comment: Place below code in top of the page and this will create test.pdf on same folder where your file is..
 
<cfdocument format="pdf" filename="#expandPath('./test.pdf')#" overwrite="true">
   <cfdump var="#form#">
   <cfdump var="#url#">
  </cfdocument>